# 'class' object has no attribute 'ImageTk'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

im working on getting images on buttons instead of text for UI purposes, i have no experience working with images on UI, so im looking for some guidance, when i pass the image i get the error:

AttributeError: 'Open_Template' object has no attribute 'ImageTk'

Maybe someone can explain what am i missing to pass the ImageTk into the class?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import datetime
import tkinter as tk
import webbrowser
import pytz
import openpyxl

class Main_App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top",fill="both",expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        self.frames= {}

        for F in (test1,test2):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F]=frame

            frame.grid (row=0, column = 0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(test1)

    def show_frame(self,cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

def SetMenu(self,parent,controller):

    Button1= tk.Button(self,relief='flat',command=lambda:controller.show_frame(test1))
    Button1.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky="nsew")
    Button1.config(image=self.ImageTk.PhotoImage(file ="image.gif"))


class test1(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        SetMenu(self,parent, controller)

class test2(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        SetMenu(self,parent, controller)

app=Main_App()
app.mainloop()
```

so, found a way to make it work. which is

```
Button1=Button(self,bg="white",relief='flat',command=lambda:controller.show_frame(test1))
Button1.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky="nsew")
self.ph_im4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "image.gif")
Button1.config(image=self.ph_im4)
```

but this kind of beats the purpose of what im trying to do, hence i would need to be able to load the image without the variable, or i would have to create like 500 variables to load and map every image manually

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why did you add self to ImageTk?

```
Button1.config(image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file ="image.gif"))
```

If you need prevent garbage collector:

```
def SetMenu(self,parent,controller):

    self.button1_image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file ="image.gif")
    Button1= tk.Button(self,relief='flat',command=lambda:controller.show_frame(test1))
    Button1.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky="nsew")
    Button1.config(image=self.button1_image)
    Button1.image=self.button1_image
```

Comment: if i dont pass it as self it does not load the image, it becomes a white square, i dont get an error from sublime text tho.

Comment: Your solution will create a local instance of `ImageTk.PhotoImage` inside `SetMenu()` function, and the instance will be garbage collected after `SetMenu()` is completed.

Comment: @JoshRodriguez The solution you mentioned in your post is one of the way.  But I don't understand why you said it is not applicable to your design.

Comment: @acw1668 the idea here is to have a constructor, that assigns the image to the button.
If i use the same variable to assign it to another button, the first one will have the image deleted, and button becomes a square of the bg color

Comment: Then you can attach the image reference to the assigned button.  For example, if the button variable named `btn`, then `btn.image = image`.